# How to create a business logic for regular expression and save data to csv file

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark

We have .txt log file , i used scala spark to read the file. the file contains sets of data in row wise . i read the data one by one like as below

```
val sc = spark.SparkContext
val dataframe = sc.textFile(/path/to/log/*.txt)
```

We have .txt log file , i used scala spark to read the file. the file contains sets of data in row wise . i read the data one by one like as below

```
val sc = spark.SparkContext
val dataframe = sc.textFile(/path/to/log/*.txt)
```

val get_set_element = sc.textFile(filepath.txt)

```
val pattern = """(\S+) "([\S\s]+)\" (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+)""".r

val test =  get_set_element.map{ line =>
    ( for {
        m <- pattern.findAllIn(line).matchData
        g <- m.subgroups
      } yield(g)
    ).toList
  }.
  map(l => (l(0), l(1), l(2), l(3), l(4), l(5)))
```

I want to create a DataFrame so that i can save it into csv file.

Comment: Please write the reason for downvote

Comment: Hey Jackson! I think the reason people are downvoting your question is that it does not provide a lot of context, or in other words, it leaves a bunch of guesswork to the person trying to answer your question. Good practice is to give a short example of what you are doing, e.g. "I have this file with this format. The result I'm looking for is this and that", then show what you've tried so far, and finally explain what the error is and what you're expecting instead. You have some of these elements, but they could use a bit more work :)

Comment: I'd personally expand on what's going wrong beyond "I'm unable to do so". Also try to only use abbreviations where necessary and obvious in the context of a tool. I had to google RDD (spark specific I guess). Does DF stand for data file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be created from RDD[Row], with schema assigned:

```
// instead of: map(l => (l(0), l(1), l(2), l(3), l(4), l(5)))
.map(Row.fromSeq)
val fields = (0 to 5).map(idx => StructField(name = "l" + idx, dataType = StringType, nullable = true))
val df = spark.createDataFrame(test, StructType(fields))
```

Output:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|l0 |l1 |l2 |l3 |l4 |l5 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|a  |b  |c  |d  |e  |f  |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```